# Can I set link field href with setValues in admin form?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, blocks, magento-1, adminform

Whenever I render a `link` type in admin form field, I often ends up loading the model to render the `href` with `$helper->getUrl(...)`.

Is there a way I can render the link contents, including href and label, with `$form->setValues()` like other fields?

**Example:**

I don't want this:

```
$form->addField('link_to_somewhere', 'link', array(
'label' => 'Click me',
'href'  => 'http://...',
));
```

I want something like this:

```
$form->addField('link_to_somewhere', 'link', array(
  'label' => 'Click me',
));

$form->setValues(array(
  'link_to_somewhere' => 'http://...'
));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can natively with the **Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link**

```
$fieldset->addField('link', 'link', array(
            'name'      => 'link name',
            'href'      => 'http://google.com',
            'value'     => 'my link to google',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Link label'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Link Title'),
    ));
```

You can check all the Element type available by browsing the *magentoroot/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element* directory

**NOTE** : the 'value' is overwrite if you call **setValue()** on the form. Double check that you don't have a line like this below your field declaration

```
 $form->setValues($model->getData());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the opposite of what I wanted, edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Erf. ok !

You can't use the link element from Varien but you can create your own. I'll make a post a bit later.

Answer (score 4):

Ok ! After the comment and the edit, I've understand your need.

The problem you have is that the **Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link** use the value as the link label and not as the href.

So all you have to do is... create your own form element.

**First, create your own class extending Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link**

```
class Namespace_Module_Lib_Varien_Data_Form_Element_Customlink extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link
{
    /**
     * Generates element html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $html = $this->getBeforeElementHtml();
        $html .= '<a id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).' href="' . $this->getEscapedValue()  . '">'. $this->getLinkLabel() . "</a>\n";
        $html .= $this->getAfterElementHtml();
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare array of anchor attributes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHtmlAttributes()
    {
        return array_diff(parent::getHtmlAttributes(), array('href'));
    }
}
```

**Then, declare your custom type in your form**

```
$fieldset->addType('custom_link','Namespace_Module_Lib_Varien_Data_Form_Element_Customlink');
```

**Finally, use it :)**

```
$fieldset->addField('link', 'custom_link', array(
            'link_label' => 'Click me !',
            'label'      => Mage::helper('core')->__('Link label'),
            'title'      => Mage::helper('core')->__('Link Title'),
    ));

[...]

$form->addValues(array(
  'link' => 'http://...'
));
```

**EDIT**
I've test it and used addValues() instead of setValues() to avoid removing the values already sets.

Any case, it works !

Comment: This makes a lot sense already. I don't have time to give this a test yet, I'll accept when one of us prove it working.